# WPF ProgressBar initial state and grid issue when it's running

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 issues I can't figure out:

- When the application starts, the `ProgressBar` is filled in by
  default before I even execute the code to update it.  My binding
  value is defaulted to 0 and I even set it to 0 again when I navigate
  to the tab where this `ProgressBar` is located... so I'm not sure why
  it's filled in.  Is this some sort of default behavior by design? 
  Once the code executes, it works just fine (goes from 0 to Max and tab switching resets it to 0).
- As soon as `ProgressBar` starts to fill, the contents of the entire
  grid shift a little to the right (like 3 pixels).  It looks very
  ugly and I have no idea why this is happening.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBarDiagnostics"
             Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
             Value="{Binding Diagnostics.ProgressValue,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Maximum="{Binding Diagnostics.ProgressMaximum}" 
             Height="22"/>
```

Comment: More code would help us solve your problem

Comment: .NET won't set the `ProgressBar.Value` to the max value on its own. You have some code somewhere that is doing this. But you haven't provided a good code example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks.  I just actually found the issue.  My default bound Value and Maximum objects were set to 0 so the ProgressBar went to Maximum of 0 by default.